# error in GCM Java server

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

hey guys i have a java GCM server and when i run this i get this line of errors

```
Sending POST to GCM

Sending 'POST' request to URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Response Code: 400
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at POST2GCM.post(POST2GCM.java:45)
    at App.main(App.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at POST2GCM.post(POST2GCM.java:41)
    ... 1 more
```

before i got an error about the fail_on_empty_beans but i've already found a solution. guys please help.

Comment: Seem something is wrong in your post parameter.

Comment: where, i just copied my code in a tutorial i found online. please point it out and tell me what to do so i can fix it

Comment: i think `400` is bad request, so check the data being sent (your params)

Answer (score 0):

Your json string should be in the below format

```
String postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + CLIENT_REG_ID + "\" ],\"delay_while_idle\": true,\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"My Ticket\",\"contentTitle\":\"My Title\",\"message\": \"Test GCM message from GCMServer-Android\"}}";
```

As answered in the thread

```
POST from Java or JS to GCM
```

```
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //Create connection
            String postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + CLIENT_REG_ID + "\" ],\"delay_while_idle\": true,\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"My Ticket\",\"contentTitle\":\"My Title\",\"message\": \"Test GCM message from GCMServer-Android\"}}";
            URL url = new URL("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=API_KEY");
            connection.connect();
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(postData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
            InputStream stream = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            //put output stream into a string
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

is it in the createData method here

```
public class Content implements Serializable{

    private List<String> registration_ids;
    private Map<String,String> data;

    public void addRegId(String regId){
        if(registration_ids == null)
            registration_ids = new LinkedList<String>();
        registration_ids.add(regId);
    }

    public void createData(String title, String message){
        if(data == null)
            data = new HashMap<String,String>();

        data.put("title", title);
        data.put("message", message);

    }
}
```

Comment: hey, guys still there